How can longest strictly increasing subarray problem have overlapping subproblems
In the longest strictly increasing subarray problem, we have an array A, and we need to find the longest subarray such that in that subarray S, S[k]>S[k-1].
Since we can divide the array A into subarrays, how are overlapping subproblems criteria applicable to this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14492948/12862712 useful for this?

The linked question and the accepted answer are rather misguided. There is nothing in the longest increasing subarray "problem" (as opposed to the longest increasing subsequence problem) that warrants anything remotely related to DP. The former is completely trivial.
